# Gradle declaration to suppress 'unchecked' warnings not working

Tags: java, gradle, suppress-warnings

Gradle 4.x here. I have the following declaration in my `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

My *understanding* was that this should suppress all "unchecked"-related compiler warnings. However when I run `./gradlew clean build` I still see them:

```
/Users/myuser/my-app/src/main/java/com/example/myapp/screens/DoSomethingScreen.java:56: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        priceListListBox = getList("priceListListBox");
                                  ^
  required: JList<String>
  found:    JList
1 warning
```

What can I do to suppress these warnings and why is my Gradle declaration not working as expected?